# How to change a specific value in file with ansible

Tags: regex, linux, ansible, adhoc

I am new to ansible.
I have about 50 servers where I have to change a username and password in the file `/etc/nova/nova.conf`

```
Line: 3102 OS_USERNAME = ABC123 (OLD)  
Line: 3103 OS_PASSWORD = xxXXxx (OLD)
```

with new credentials

```
Line: 3102 OS_USERNAME = DEF123 (NEW)  
Line: 3103 OS_PASSWORD = vvVVvv (NEW)
```

Comment: Hi Muzzamil, welcome to SO. Your question is not clear on what you are trying to achieve, what is actually happening and what you tried. Please read [**how to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**how to create a minimum, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better results when using the site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [`lineinfile` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html).  For your example above:

```
- name: Update username in nova.conf
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/nova/nova.conf
    regexp: '^OS_USERNAME'
    line: OS_USERNAME = DEF123
```

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you very much Mark, i never knew this portal is that helpful,